# In ACF, how to show custom category selection tab upon selecting a main category

Tags: categories, advanced-custom-fields

I have 3 main categories with some subcategories which looks like below.

```
Universities
 - A
 - B
 - C

Schools
 - D
 - E
 - F

Nurseries
 - G
 - H
 - I
```

How do i set up in ACF settings so that if i select **Universities**, only A,B,C should come and if i select **Schools**, only D,E,F should come and so on.

I have tried the below setup on ACF but it is returning all the categories. Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding your question. You are creating a Custom Field Called University and you want the fields within this Custom Field (ABC) to only be displayed when the user is creating/editing a new University?

Comment: Not custom Field. I have categories and sub-categories. I want to show the subcategories in a separate tab box when a main category is selected.